# Fixture for a product's group price not working

Tags: magento-enterprise, ecomdev-phpunit, group-price, unit-tests, phpunit

I'm using EcomDev_PHPUnit on Magento EE 1.14.2.1, and am trying to set up a simple unit test for a configurable and simple product which have group prices associated, but I'm not having any luck getting the fixture to work.

My test:

```
# File: .../ObserverTest.php
/**
 * @loadFixture stores
 * @loadFixture
 */
public function testGroupPriceExample()
{
    $configurable = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1);
    var_dump($configurable->getData('group_price'));
}
```

For now, I just want to output the `group_price` as happens when I do this through the observer subject class that I want to test.

My fixtures:

```
# File: fixtures/stores.yaml
scope:
    website:
        - website_id: 1
          code: us_eng
          name: United States
          default_group_id: 1
    group:
        - group_id: 1
          website_id: 1
          name: United States
          default_store_id: 1
          root_category_id: 2
    store:
        - store_id: 1
          website_id: 1
          group_id: 1
          code: us_eng
          name: United States
```

The stores fixture works fine, and I have used it in plenty of other unit tests.

The product fixture:

```
# File: fixtures/testGroupPriceExample.yaml
# Set up a configurable with group pricing and a bunch of simples without
eav:
    catalog_product:
        - entity_id: 1
          sku: 12345/RED/
          name: Configurable
          attribute_set_id: 4
          entity_type_id: 4
          type_id: configurable
          group_price: test
        - entity_id: 2
          sku: 12345/RED/S
          attribute_set_id: 4
          entity_type_id: 4
          name: Some simple
          type_id: simple
        - entity_id: 3
          sku: 12345/RED/M
          attribute_set_id: 4
          entity_type_id: 4
          name: Another simple
          type_id: simple
tables:
    # Set up the simple/configurable relationships
    catalog/product_relation:
        - parent_id       : 1
          child_id        : 2
        - parent_id       : 1
          child_id        : 2
    # Set up the customer group
    customer/customer_group:
        - customer_group_id: 4
          customer_group_code: Loyalty Group
          tax_class_id: 3
```

I've tried a bunch of different ways of getting a group price set, e.g. under `tables: catalog/product_group_price` (results in fixture load failure), `eav: catalog/product_group_price` (same), directly as an attribute on the product entity e.g. `group_price: 123.00` and still I always get `NULL` from the `var_dump` in my unit test.

Has anyone created a group price fixture before and could point me in the direction of how to do it?

FYI the stores fixture is in place so that I can fixture a product's group price to be say "$25.99" for Loyalty Group (group_id 4) and the US website (website_id 1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remove the `group_price` attribute from your product fixture and assign a proper price that is higher than the group price, e.g.

```
eav:
    catalog_product:
        - entity_id: 1
          […]
          price: 29.99
```

Second, use the correct table alias for your group price fixture, e.g.

```
tables:
    […]
    catalog/product_attribute_group_price:
        - value_id: 1
          entity_id: 1
          all_groups: 0
          customer_group_id: 4
          value: 25.99
          website_id: 0
```

Third, in your test method, make sure your "customer" is in a customer group that a group price can be applied to, e.g.

```
$sessionMock = $this->getModelMock(
    'customer/session',
    array('init', 'getCustomerGroupId')
);
$sessionMock
    ->expects($this->any())
    ->method('getCustomerGroupId')
    ->willReturn(4)
;
$this->replaceByMock('singleton', 'customer/session', $sessionMock);
```

And finally, test whatever is important to be tested, e.g.

```
$configurable = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1);
$this->assertNotNull($configurable->getGroupPrice());
$this->assertLessThan($configurable->getPrice(), $configurable->getGroupPrice());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So is the key having a price value higher than the group price?

Comment: Regarding the `null` value, the key is to have any price value. To actually retrieve the group price as defined, it needs to be lower than the original price.

Comment: Hi again, thanks for that. I think my problem is bigger than just the fixture in that I can't actually retrieve any of the EAV data. Anyway, this fixture format correctly inserts the data in the database so answer accepted. Help on my new question would be appreciated :) thanks!